# Powershell script to create website in IIS

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me with creation of website from power shell.Script i have written below is not working .

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

#navigate to the app pools root
cd IIS:\AppPools\

#check if the app pool exists
if (!(Test-Path $iisAppPoolName -pathType container))
{
    #create the app pool
    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
}

#navigate to the sites root
cd IIS:\Sites\

#check if the site exists
if (Test-Path $iisAppName -pathType container)
{
    return
}

#create the site
$iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:" + $iisAppName} -physicalPath $directoryPath
$iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value $iisAppPoolName
```

Comment: you didnt write this script, you copied it directly from the following site: [original writer of script](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2013/02/24/create-iis-app-pool-and-site-with-windows-powershell.aspx) and didn't use their variable declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey you just have to implement below lines after import modules:-

```
$iisAppPoolName = "my-test-app"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"
$iisAppName = "my-test-app.test"
$directoryPath = "D:\SomeFolder"
```

Please let me know if you have any concern.

Answer (score 13):

For me New-Item did not work, I had to use New-WebSite like this:

```
$SiteName = "MySite"
$HostName = "localhost"
$SiteFolder = Join-Path -Path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' -ChildPath $SiteName

New-WebSite -Name $SiteName -PhysicalPath $SiteFolder -Force
$IISSite = "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName"
Set-ItemProperty $IISSite -name  Bindings -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="*:443:$HostName"}
```

Then start the Website:

```
Start-WebSite -Name $SiteName
```